# always null pointer exception

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

sorry for asking an odd question, I'm new in java and I will make an android app which can make a counting from c = a + b
but it always return nullpointerexception

here is my code

```
public class Kreasi extends Activity {

    // Inisialisasi
    private EditText e1;
    private EditText e2;

    private Spinner s1;

    private Button b1;
    private Button b2;

    private TextView t1;
    private TextView t2;
    private TextView t3;
    private TextView t4;
    private TextView t5;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.kreasi);

        // INISIALISASI VARIABEL
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isiharga);
        e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isilaba);

        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spin);

        b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.process);
        b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reset);

        t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hMax);
        t2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.angPokok);
        t3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.angSewa);
        t4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.angTotal);

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            int a,b;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                hideSoftKeyboard(b1);

                String aa,bb;

                aa = e1.getText().toString();
                bb = e2.getText().toString();

                a = Integer.valueOf(aa);
                b = Integer.valueOf(bb);

                int c = (int) (a + b);
                t1.setText(Integer.toString(c));

            }

        });

    }

    // Menyembunyikan Keyboard
    public void hideSoftKeyboard(Button btn) {
        btn.setInputType(0);
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(btn.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }

    /*
    // Fungsi saat tombol process ditekan
    public void tombolprocess(){

        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                hideSoftKeyboard(b1);

                aa = e1.getText().toString();
                bb = e2.getText().toString();

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"a="+aa +" b=" +bb,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
    */
}
```

thanks for any advice

Comment: *Where* is the NPE occurring?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you're not passing value for `e2`.

Simply change:

```
e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isiharga);
e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isilaba);
```

to

```
e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isiharga);
e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isilaba);
```

Comment: And this, folks, is why we don't just name our variables `var1`, `var2`, ..., `varN`.

Answer (score 3):

You've set `e1` twice, you need to set `e2` also, like so

```
e1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isiharga);
e2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.isilaba);
```